# R is reading what should be a "digital" variable as an analog one

Tags: r, variables

I'm trying to perform an ANOVA test in R to look at the effect two different treatments. Unfortunately, one of my variables is digital but R is treating it as if it were analog.Essentially, plants were given 10, 20, or 30% sunlight, but R is performing the ANOVA test as if this were continuous rather than discrete.

How can I get R to see my variable as a digital one? Thanks so much.

Comment: The usual term is "categorical variable", and this is typically implemented in R by reassigning the variable as a `factor`: `sunlight <- as.factor(sunlight)`.

Comment: I'd probably use an ordered factor instead.